# How to lock mouse and keyboard under Wayland

Tags: fedora, screen-lock, wayland

*Pyxtrlock* is a program to lock a workstation while still displaying the screen.  That is, keyboard and mouse can not be used until a password is typed on the keyboard, but the contents of the display isn't hidden.  Fedora 25 switched to using Wayland by default, and *pyxtrlock* doesn't effectively the lock any more.

Is there a way to do this kind of lock under Wayland?

(I'm aware I could revert to using Gnome under X again.  But I would like to continue to use Wayland, so I'm looking for a solution in the new environment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is not possible on a compositor-agnostic basis in Wayland. You'd need to get this to be supported by the compositor (e.g Gnome in your case), or have the compositor expose a way (e.g via a wayland protocol) to "lock" the mouse and keyboard so that you can modify Pyxtrlock to work with that compositor.